# Can I use an SSH alias as part of a hostname?

Tags: ssh, hostname

I have a bunch of machines under one domain that I frequently connect to;
`apollo.my.university.edu` `hades.my.university.edu` `zeus.my.university.edu`
and I use the same configuration settings for each of them. Instead of typing them all out in my `.ssh/config`,

```
Host apollo
    Hostname apollo.my.university.edu

Host hades
    Hostname hades.my.university.edu

Host zeus
    Hostname zeus.my.university.edu
```

is there a makefile-esque way to use the alias to complete the hostname for all of them simultaneously? Something like

```
Host apollo hades zeus
    Hostname *.my.university.edu
```

Comment: Off-topic here, but I really would love to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
Host apollo hades zeus
    Hostname %h.my.university.edu
```

If I am reading `man ssh_config` correctly, this should do what you want.

```
HostName
         Specifies the real host name to log into.  This can be used to specify nicknames
         or abbreviations for hosts.  If the hostname contains the character sequence
         `%h', then this will be replaced with the host name specified on the command
         line (this is useful for manipulating unqualified names).  The default is the
         name given on the command line.  Numeric IP addresses are also permitted (both
         on the command line and in HostName specifications).
```

Comment: Off topic, but you can find a lot of nice config tricks [here](http://blogs.perl.org/users/smylers/2011/08/ssh-productivity-tips.html)

Answer (score 3):

Besides using `ssh_config` as shown by demure, you can also make DNS lookups consider your domain if there is no other match. To do so, add the following to the `/etc/resolv.conf` file:

```
search my.university.edu
```

In this way, you do not even need to add the hosts to `~/.ssh/config`. `ssh zeus` and the resolver finds the right host for you. Since it happens on the resolver level, it also works for other programs such as `curl` and Firefox.

Note that programs like NetworkManager overwrite `resolv.conf`. In the case of NetworkManager, you need to change the *Search Domain* setting to `my.university.edu`.

Documentation:

- [`resolv.conf(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf)